# Why doesn't my f:ajax work with h:selectOneMenu?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

Using JSF 2.0, Glassfish 3.2, Primefaces 2.2.1

I have a page with several composite components.  In one of these components, I have an h:selectOneMenu.  I am trying to add f:ajax to call a method when a new value is selected.

Here is what the h:selectOneMenu component in the page looks like:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectRmDD" styleClass="editSelectRmDD" value="#{scheduleEditSessionBean.selectedRoom}" >
    <f:selectItems id="roomList" value="#{scheduleEditSessionBean.roomList}"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{scheduleEditSessionBean.selectRmDD_processValueChange}" event="valueChange" render="@form" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

When I select a new item from the h:selectOneMenu, the listener function gets called, but the value in **selectedRoom** is null.  I have looked at this in the debugger as well and even the submittedValue for the component in the AjaxBehaviorEvent is also null.  Here is the method that is called when a new value is selected and the definition for selectedRoom:

```
 public void selectRmDD_processValueChange( AjaxBehaviorEvent ae) {
    String s = getSelectedRoom();
    System.out.println( "Selected room = "+s );
    if( s != null )applyRoomBtn_action();
 }

private String selectedRoom = "1";
public String getSelectedRoom() { return this.selectedRoom; }
public void setSelectedRoom(String s) { this.selectedRoom = s; }
```

Any ideas why the value isn't being filled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That will happen when the `SelectItem` of the `roomList` has `null` or empty string as value at the point the form submit is been processed. No other causes comes to mind, expect of maybe a `Converter` for `String.class` which is not doing its job properly, but that should have affected all inputs which are bound to a `String` property.