# selectoneMenu change event doesn't work with one value

Tags: jsf-2, selectonemenu

I have two dropdown menus in my program, the second one gets populated based on the selected value from the first.

When there is only one value in first menu, the second menu is not reflecting the values, but it works when I have more than one value. What could be causing the error?

Here is the code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="blSearchFacilityInput"
                 value="#{bLDashBoardAction.facilityId}" style="width:80px;">
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="blSearchzoneInput"
            listener="#{bLDashBoardAction.facValueChangeEvent}"/> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{bLDashBoardAction.svaFaciltyList}" var="c"
                   itemLabel="#{c.facCode}" itemValue="#{c.id}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectOneMenu id="blSearchzoneInput" value="#{bLDashBoardAction.zoneId}"
                 style="width:80px;">
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="blSearchSectorInput"
            listener="#{bLDashBoardAction.zoneValueChangeEvent}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bLDashBoardAction.zoneList}" var="c"
                   itemLabel="#{c.zoneCode}" itemValue="#{c.zoneId}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Looks at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757571/why-doesnt-my-fajax-work-with-hselectonemenu

Comment: Do you initialize `#{bLDashBoardAction.facilityId}` with a default value in your backing bean?

Comment: From your question, I am guessing that your first dropdown has the options shown, but no value assigned. And as it isn't possible to change it for another value, the update of the second menu is never triggered. Could that be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one item which is by default already preselected, then there's effectively no change when you attempt to select it once again. You really need a physical second item in order to trigger the change event.

Add another item with a `null` value or a `noSelectionOption="true"`.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="blSearchFacilityInput"
                 value="#{bLDashBoardAction.facilityId}" style="width:80px;">
    <f:ajax render="blSearchzoneInput"
            listener="#{bLDashBoardAction.facValueChangeEvent}"/> 
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--select one--" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bLDashBoardAction.svaFaciltyList}" var="c"
                   itemLabel="#{c.facCode}" itemValue="#{c.id}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Now you can successfully trigger the value change event. Note that it's the default event already, so I omitted it from the code for brevity. No need to repeat the defaults.

An alternative is to just automatically prefill the child dropdown if there's only one item in the parent dropdown. E.g., directly after that moment when you fill the `svaFacilityList`:

```
if (svaFaciltyList.size() == 1) {
    zoneList = fillItBasedOn(svaFaciltyList.get(0));
}
```